# Convert primitive Datatypes to NSNumber

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsnumber, primitive

We are trying to write a Wrapper from  `NSObject` (using primitive datatypes) to a `NSManagedObject` (using `NSNumber`).
So we have to automatically convert the primitive type to a `NSNumber`.

We know the `objCType` through `NSInvocation` (`[invocation.methodSignature getArgumentTypeAtIndex:2]`) and also get the value to set (`[invocation getArgument:&argument atIndex:2]`) this way.

So the problem is: How to use this information to create a `NSNumber` out of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify, are you saying you currently have an NSObject subclass with x number of properties / accessors of type float, int, whatever, and you want some way of generating an NSManagedObject with those accessors of type NSNumber? Have you already defined the NSManagedObject subclass, because you can just define the properties / accessors to use the primitive types instead.

Comment: Yeah kind of... My problem is that I have a protocol (which uses floats, ints, long longs,...)  and my NSManagedObject have to implement this Protocol - so I'm looking for a way to achieve this. How can I define which property should use which primitive type? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This popped into my rss this evening and looks just like what you are after : http://www.cimgf.com/2012/01/11/handling-incoming-json-redux/

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches to do this. They're all outlined under **[Non-Standard Persistent Attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html)** in the Core Data documentation.

Core Data will then convert your data on the fly to / from what you need.

Comment: Thanks... but this approach was clear to me. My idea was to if it's possible to solve this problem without having to write to much custom code.

Comment: Can you be more specific (samples) what you are trying to convert from and to?